# Can't access Dashboard after WordPress 3.3 Update?

Tags: cms

Hi I am having a problem, I updated my wordpress site to version 3.3 and the site itself seems to be working fine except I cant log into the dashboard anymore.

When I login using my admin details it keeps re-directing me to /forums/profile page for admin user. Please can anyone help me out or has anyone came across this problem before?

Thanks
Louise
[image]

Comment: If you are using any dashboard related plugins, it may be conflicting with the new setup. Try disabling all your plugins (by temporarily renaming the files in your wp-content/plugins folder) and try accessing.

Comment: Also, it will help if you can provide a screenshot or tell us the exact error that you are encountering, we will be able to provide a better solution. :)

Comment: Hi Thankyou for the advice, I changed the name of the simple-forum plugin and it let me have access a panel like the image above, however this is not full admin access, where are the menu's to the left? None of the other plugins had any change only this one, Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: It is as if I dont have full access anymore because when I try and go to /update-core.php or /tools.php etc, I get a "you have insufficient priveleges" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, seems like the user permissions got changed. Did you have a plugin that manages user roles?

Anyhow, I'm assuming that you have database access. Check the role that has been assigned to the user.

You may have to change this manually to an administrator by editing the database.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to manually change to an administrator in the database?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you would know how to. Please follow @Kash's answer :) Hope your ordeal is solved. :)